# breezejs issues with the save bundle

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, json, breeze

im working with breezejs, and the server-side code of my app is .net.

in my views (client side), i want to add and entity then i want to save it. Lets assume that an entity is like this :

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "someName",
  "CreatedDate": "1900-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  "UpdatedDate": "1900-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  "CreatedBy": null,
  "UpdatedBy": null,
  "RowVersion": 0,
   etc ...
  }
}
```

i want to set the values of `CreatedDate` `UpdatedDate` `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy`, i can do that using javascript of course, BUT i dont want the client to take care of those kind of things.

my breeze controller where lives this function is like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
{
    return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
 }
```

as u can see the saveBundle is a JObject, when i debug i see the saveBundle like this:

```
{
"entities": [
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "someName",
  "CreatedDate": "1900-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  "UpdatedDate": "1900-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  "CreatedBy": null,
  "UpdatedBy": null,
  "RowVersion": 0,
   etc ...
    }
  }
}
],
"saveOptions": {}
}
```

How can i change the values of `CreatedDate` `UpdatedDate` `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy` in the saveBundle before the save is commited ???

this is a JObject with an array of objects as proprety, i can manipulate Json with javascript, how can i do it with .Net ???

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Jay Traband post I finally found a way to make changes to an entity before saving it.

I overloaded the `BeforeSaveEntity` like this :

```
protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo) {
        // Return false if don´t want to  save the entity
        var entityType = entityInfo.Entity.GetType();

        if (entityInfo.Entity.GetType() == typeof(MyEntityTypeModel))
        {
            if (entityInfo.EntityState == EntityState.Added)
            // It can be 'Modified' or 'Deleted'
            {
                var MyModel = entityInfo.Entity as MyEntityTypeModel;

                MyModel.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                MyModel.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                string username = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
                MyModel.CreatedBy = username;
                MyModel.UpdatedBy = username;
            }
        }
        return true;
   }
```

Thanks a lot, and I hope this will help someone someday.

Comment: I was running around with the same problem and everywhere I see the answer is 'BeforeSaveEntities'. I doubt that this introduce a design-level problem because we are forced to do all business-level manipulations inside the DataContextProvider, which should ideally have been done inside the repository. What if we have 10+ such entities to modify before save? Are we going to use a swich-case to check the entity type and do the modifications? What is the best practice we can follow?

Comment: Note that you would also need to update the OriginalValuesMap when modifying an Entity, e.g. entityInfo.OriginalValuesMap["UpdatedDate"] = null;
more info here -> http://breeze.github.io/doc-net/contextprovider.html#OriginalValuesMap

Answer (score 3):

You can intercept Breeze's server side save process by using the *ContextProvider's* virtual *BeforeSaveEntity* and *BeforeSaveEntities* methods.  The documentation [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider-methods) and [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider) has more information on this topic.

For example, you can override *BeforeSaveEntities* with code something like the following.

```
protected override Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveEntities(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap) {

   foreach (var type in saveMap.Keys) {
     var list = saveMap[type];
      foreach (var entityInfo in list) {
         var entity = entityInfo.Entity;
         // .. do something interesting here
      }
 }
```

Comment: yeah i agree, but how can i inspect the `EntityInfo` object ?

Comment: I added an example to the previous answer.